# Chess terms in Japanese

Tags: translation

I'm working on an open-source accessibility extension for the chess website (lichess.org) - I tried to translate it to Japanese, can you take a look if I mistranslated something?

- takes (captures): とる
- promotion: プロモーション
- short castle: キャスリングショート
- long castle: キャスリングロング
- move! (as in "You should make a move!"): 行く！

Comment: Welcome to the Japanese Language Stack Exchange. Proofreading requests are off topic. Surely there are chess term glossaries available?

Comment: @Leebo I edited my questions to include only terms that I couldn't find a solid source for.

Comment: Probably [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3#%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%EF%BC%88%E6%98%87%E6%A0%BC%E3%83%BB%E6%88%90%E3%82%8B%EF%BC%89) and [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0) answer your questions except _move_, which is most probably translated as 動かす but depends on the exact phrase you want to use.

Comment: A gentle suggestion — I'm worried about the quality of the translation if you are having trouble with vocabulary items like these. For example, are you aware that "X takes Y" could not possibly be translated word-for-word from English into Japanese?

Answer (score 1):

The majority of chess terminology in Japanese is simply katakana transliterations of the English terms. You can find them all on Wikipedia (in Japanese) [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%82%B9%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7).

By the way, this even extends to complete verb phrases, which are also rendered into phonetic transliterations. For example, in English, a commentator might say "Knight takes f7", referring to a capture by a knight on the f7 square. In Japanese, this would be ナイト　テイク　エフ　セブン (knight take f seven). It's interesting that the transliteration doesn't include the correct 3rd person form of the verb (takes), but I'm not sure why that quirk evolved. I suspect that all captures and conjugations of verbs relating to captures have been subsumed into テイク (take). The verb とる (or とっていく) is also used to describe captures in general analysis (as opposed to spoken versions of chess notation).

The verb for moving a piece is 指す, but as above, it's common to just use the English terminology. e.g. Bishop c6 = ビショップ　シー　シックス. In general analysis, you can say things like ナイトがジーファイブと指す (knight moves to g5).

There seem to be some deviations from English which resemble 和製英語. For example, a pawn advance is ポーンプッシュ (pawn push), which has a slightly different nuance from the English term 'pawn push'. I'm sure there are other examples, but I'm not an expert so I defer to the answers of others.

Comment: "I'm not sure why that quirk evolved" it's not a quirk, it's how the majority of language borrowing happens. We usually say grafitti (plural in the original Italian) instead of grafitto, the French don't think about the original meaning of "week" (from "weekend") or "footing", and so on. It would be weirder, really, if Japanese speakers with rudimentary/no English preserved the original grammar of English. ドンマイ doesn't have an object ('don't mind **it**'), nouns like エール (yell) and エスカレーター aren't pluralized to エールズ or エスカレーターズ, etc.

Comment: Good point, thanks.